# Averaging two columns into a third column

Tags: r, average

I currently have a table in R with 4 columns and I want to average the last two columns (titled W10CP1 and W10CP2) into a 5th column of that table.

I tried to use rowMeans but I got an error.

Sorry for the basic question!

Comment: How did you use it and what is the error?  Based on the info, it should be `rowMeans(tbl[,c("W10CP1", "W10CP2)], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: what is the result of `sapply(yourDATA,class)`

Comment: When you post a question on SO that references an error, it does us no good to say "*I got an error*". Which one? There are countless. Please quickly read about [reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), as well as SO's help-pages on [minimal, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll get more relevant comments/answers quickly if you follow their advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the tydeverse package here an example:

`library(tidyverse)

data<-data%>%
            mutate(mean= (data[,-1] +data[,-2]/2))`